# Get the title of the current active Window/Document in Mac OS X

Tags: python, objective-c, macos

Refering to a previously asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373020/finding-the-current-active-window-in-mac-os-x-using-python), I would like to know how to get the title of the current active document.

I tried the script mention in the answers to the question above. This works, but only gives me the name of the application. For example, I am writing this question: When I fire up the script it gives me the name of the application, i.e. "Firefox". This is pretty neat, but does not really help. I would rather like to capture the title of my current active document. See the image.

[Firefox title http://img.skitch.com/20090126-nq2egknhjr928d1s74i9xixckf.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090126-nq2egknhjr928d1s74i9xixckf.jpg)

I am using Leopard, so no backward compatibility needed. Also I am using Python's Appkit to gain access to the NSWorkspace class, but if you tell me the Objective-C code, I could figure out the translation to Python.

---

Ok, I've got a solution which is not very satisfing, thats why I don't mark Koen Bok's answer. At least not yet.

```
tell application "System Events"
set frontApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
end tell
tell application frontApp
if the (count of windows) is not 0 then
    set window_name to name of front window
end if
end tell
```

Save as script and invoke it with osascript from the shell.

Comment: Thank you for the applescript solution. Did you ever find a way to do it via python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know your best bet is wrapping an AppleScript. But AppleScript is magic to me so I leave it as an exercise for the questioner :-)

This might help a little: [A script to resize frontmost two windows to fill screen - Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060105082728937)

Answer (score 8):

In Objective-C, the short answer, using a little Cocoa and mostly the [Carbon Accessibility API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityCarbonRef/Reference/reference.html) is:

```m
// Get the process ID of the frontmost application.
NSRunningApplication* app = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
                              frontmostApplication];
pid_t pid = [app processIdentifier];

// See if we have accessibility permissions, and if not, prompt the user to
// visit System Preferences.
NSDictionary *options = @{(id)kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt: @YES};
Boolean appHasPermission = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(
                             (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options);
if (!appHasPermission) {
   return; // we don't have accessibility permissions

// Get the accessibility element corresponding to the frontmost application.
AXUIElementRef appElem = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid);
if (!appElem) {
  return;
}

// Get the accessibility element corresponding to the frontmost window
// of the frontmost application.
AXUIElementRef window = NULL;
if (AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appElem, 
      kAXFocusedWindowAttribute, (CFTypeRef*)&window) != kAXErrorSuccess) {
  CFRelease(appElem);
  return;
}

// Finally, get the title of the frontmost window.
CFStringRef title = NULL;
AXError result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(window, kAXTitleAttribute,
                   (CFTypeRef*)&title);

// At this point, we don't need window and appElem anymore.
CFRelease(window);
CFRelease(appElem);

if (result != kAXErrorSuccess) {
  // Failed to get the window title.
  return;
}

// Success! Now, do something with the title, e.g. copy it somewhere.

// Once we're done with the title, release it.
CFRelease(title);
```

Alternatively, it may be simpler to use the CGWindow API, as alluded to in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042284/308464).

Answer (score 0):

> refered to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23451568/11185460

```golang
package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -x objective-c
#cgo LDFLAGS: -framework Cocoa
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int
GetFrontMostAppPid(void){
    NSRunningApplication* app = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
                                  frontmostApplication];
    pid_t pid = [app processIdentifier];
    return pid;
}

CFStringRef
GetAppTitle(pid_t pid) {
    CFStringRef title = NULL;
    // Get the process ID of the frontmost application.
    //  NSRunningApplication* app = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]
    //                                frontmostApplication];
    //  pid_t pid = [app processIdentifier];

    // See if we have accessibility permissions, and if not, prompt the user to
    // visit System Preferences.
    NSDictionary *options = @{(id)kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt: @YES};
    Boolean appHasPermission = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(
                                 (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options);
    if (!appHasPermission) {
       return title; // we don't have accessibility permissions
    }
    // Get the accessibility element corresponding to the frontmost application.
    AXUIElementRef appElem = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid);
    if (!appElem) {
      return title;
    }

    // Get the accessibility element corresponding to the frontmost window
    // of the frontmost application.
    AXUIElementRef window = NULL;
    if (AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appElem,
          kAXFocusedWindowAttribute, (CFTypeRef*)&window) != kAXErrorSuccess) {
      CFRelease(appElem);
      return title;
    }

    // Finally, get the title of the frontmost window.
    AXError result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(window, kAXTitleAttribute,
                       (CFTypeRef*)&title);

    // At this point, we don't need window and appElem anymore.
    CFRelease(window);
    CFRelease(appElem);

    if (result != kAXErrorSuccess) {
      // Failed to get the window title.
      return title;
    }

    // Success! Now, do something with the title, e.g. copy it somewhere.

    // Once we're done with the title, release it.
    CFRelease(title);

    return title;
}
static inline CFIndex cfstring_utf8_length(CFStringRef str, CFIndex *need) {
  CFIndex n, usedBufLen;
  CFRange rng = CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(str));
  return CFStringGetBytes(str, rng, kCFStringEncodingUTF8, 0, 0, NULL, 0, need);
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/v3/process"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

//import "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/v3/process"
func cfstringGo(cfs C.CFStringRef) string {
    var usedBufLen C.CFIndex
    n := C.cfstring_utf8_length(cfs, &usedBufLen)
    if n <= 0 {
        return ""
    }
    rng := C.CFRange{location: C.CFIndex(0), length: n}
    buf := make([]byte, int(usedBufLen))

    bufp := unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0])
    C.CFStringGetBytes(cfs, rng, C.kCFStringEncodingUTF8, 0, 0, (*C.UInt8)(bufp), C.CFIndex(len(buf)), &usedBufLen)

    sh := &reflect.StringHeader{
        Data: uintptr(bufp),
        Len:  int(usedBufLen),
    }
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(sh))
}

func main() {
    pid := C.GetFrontMostAppPid()

    ps, _ := process.NewProcess(int32(pid))
    title_ref := C.CFStringRef(C.GetAppTitle(pid))

    println(pid) // pid
    println(ps.Name()) // process name
    println(cfstringGo(title_ref)) // active window title
}
```

---

I then found this property wont change after it is called.
By [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393216/objective-c-refreshing-frontmostapplication), only after we implement `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification`, we can monitor the change of activity window. But I didn't find any solution which can implement `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification` in golang.

A workaround method is compile one go program and call it by another go program. I then try full Objective-C code in [here](https://gist.github.com/sailist/02c2b1fa323dd406107b944f24c2062d#file-main-m)

Answer (score 0):

To get the active application:

```
➜ osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell (first process whose frontmost is true) to return name'
```

To get the active window's title:

```
➜ osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell (first process whose frontmost is true) to return name of window 1'
```

And to get both (to avoid a race condition where the user changes windows between the two calls):

```
➜ osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell (first process whose frontmost is true) to return {name, name of window 1}'
```

Source: https://forum.keyboardmaestro.com/t/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-frontmost-window/2711/2