# How to get another application window's title, position and size in Mac OS without Accessibility API?

Tags: cocoa, x11, accessibility-api

How can I get window's title, position and size if it does not support Accessibility API? Accessibility Inspector does not see it at all. Say, it's a xterm window in X11.app (X11->Applications->Terminal).

Comment: Do you know where can actually download Accessibility Inspector from? I hate how pages on Apple site keep moving and disappearing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to get all of this window information through the methods exposed in the CGWindow.h header file. Apple's docs are online on the [Quartz Window Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_window_services) page. They also have a very informative sample app called [Son of Grab](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SonOfGrab/Introduction/Intro.html) which should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CGWindowListCreateDescriptionFromArray(). See CGWindow.h

This gives you an array of dictionaries. The following information will probably be useful to you:

- position and size: kCGWindowBounds
- name: kCGWindowName