# How to find active window text in mac os x by c++?

Tags: c++, macos, macos-carbon

I want get active window text in mac OS x without x11.I want to use Carbon API.

Comment: definitely need image processing. Take screenshot and do image processing. No running app would ever give info like that. :P

Comment: I understand you want to use Carbon as you are writing in C++, but if the "window" is implemented using Cocoa then I don't think Carbon can access the "window text" (by which I *think* you mean the Window Title?).

Comment: yes I need Window Title.I can not use cocoa in c++.

Comment: Actually you can. Solution is Objective-C++. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it using Carbon. But you can do it using Objective-C++ and Cocoa. Just name your source file with .mm extension instead of .cpp and use any Objective-C frameworks. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039717/how-to-get-another-application-windows-title-position-and-size-in-mac-os-witho) for the details about window title