# finding the app window currently in focus on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, desktop, pyobjc

I am writing a desktop usage statistics app. It runs a background daemon which wakes up at regular intervals, finds the name of the application window currently in focus and logs that data in database.

I manage to do this on Linux desktop with help of xprop utility (you can find it [here](http://github.com/jyro2080/DesktopMeter/blob/master/src/active)).

How can I do the same on Mac OSX? Is there a direct/indirect way to do this from a python script? (PyObjC?)

Comment: Currenly implementing exactly same thing, so would like to know answer regarding MacOSX as well.

As for linux, you can use python-xlib package to get this info w/out calling other executables, like this

    import Xlib.display
    Xlib.display.Display().get_input_focus().focus.get_wm_name()

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to get the active window by using AppKit like the following

```
from AppKit import NSWorkspace

workspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
active_app = workspace.activeApplication()['NSApplicationName']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with AppleScript:

[Get the title of the current active Window/Document in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480866/get-the-title-of-the-current-active-window-document-in-mac-os-x)

You can try using appscript to generate AppleScript events from python.