# How to get which file was opened with a .exe python program

Tags: python, exe

So I am trying to create a program that would be able to read its own types of files

Imagine there is a file called *hello.world*

And you have a .exe program that you can open this file with.

This program is my python file, so what is actually the way of getting which file was opened with that .exe?

Comment: I heard you can use something like argv in the beginning of the program, but I am not sure

Comment: .exe is created afterwards, you create the algorithm then you pack it to have an exe , it's not the first step , or do you have it ready?

Comment: do you want to get the name of the file called?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324372/finding-the-app-window-currently-in-focus-on-mac-osx

Comment: @RanA , I would make the script, pack it into a .exe and then try to open the file with it. The only thing I am not sure about is how to get what file/directory of the file inside the program. Or if I am correct? xD

Comment: it's a bit unclear, the script do exactly what you program it to do , so if you program it to open a file you already have that information

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @RanA , and so I am asking about how to get that info :) About how to get the full directory of the file opened with a .exe or the contents of the file iself.

Comment: @Nitlix It seems like your code have not been written yet and you are still brainstorming, which is good. The thing is, when creating the script (before packing it into an .exe), in order for the script to work, you already need to supply it with a file name (through `argv` or of similar fashion). Therefore, the "inner script" already has that info - your packed .exe should not need any additional information on the file again. This may illustrate how to get your Python script to work with file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360389/getting-file-path-from-command-line-argument-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a small discussion in the comments:

it is possible to use **sys.argv** to get the file path:
[getting file path from command line argument in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360389/getting-file-path-from-command-line-argument-in-python)

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
print(filename)

if os.path.exists(fn):
    print os.path.basename(fn)
    # file exists
```